# Large xml validation and grouping fail messages

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to validate large xml file using xsd-schema. Here is my code:

```
    void Validate()
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, selectedXsd);
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationCallBack;
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(selectedXml, settings);
        while (reader.Read()) {}
    }
    public void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }
```

Here is my example xml file:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
        <c>two</c>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
        <c>2</c>
        <d>3</d>
    </a>
</root>
```

There are defined strong shema rules. Element `a` can only contain sub-elements `b` and `c`, both required and both integer. My program have written next errors to me:

```
The 'c' element is invalid - The value 'two' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:int' - The string 'two' is not a valid Integer value.
The element 'a' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'b, c'.
The element 'a' has invalid child element 'd'. List of possible elements expected: 'b, c'
```

Looks fine, but problem is that file have large size (> 2gb) and there may be thousands of errors. When value of specific element is invalid, it should "group" these errors despite their values. When element is missing, it should group appropriate errors, and maybe even count times they missing. Whenever different element is missing in different node, it should report another error. And so on for all possible errors. But only Information it have is string `args.Message` and `sender` which is actually XmlReader element.

My question: is there best way to do validation in my way, without parsing args.Message string and excluding out-of-memory exceptions considering huge file size? Maybe I should use another library?

Comment: It's annoying that the `XmlSchemaValidationException` class doesn't provide `GetRes` or `Args` for public. These could be nicely used for determining the type of the validation error as well as the element/value names. Then it would be just a matter of putting them into a list and going from there.

Comment: Maybe you can create a small batch before for explode the Xml file in multiple files with only one node 'a' in each. Is this way, you make an auto increment name like 1, 2, 3 for node 'a' 1, node 'a' 2 etc.
After that, you can make the control and delete all correct 'a' node and keep the wrong in the folder. In this folder, you take the name (1, 2, 3, 4 etc.) and you make your end control batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can accept a solution with a bit of reflection and want to group by general error (invalid element, not correct type etc), you could do this:

Declare a couple of variables in the class

```
Dictionary<string, List<XmlSchemaException>> exps = new Dictionary<string, List<XmlSchemaException>>();
PropertyInfo ErrorGetResProp;
```

In the validation method find the non-public property:

```
ErrorGetResProp = typeof(XmlSchemaValidationException).GetProperty("GetRes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Then in the validation callback you can gather the errors:

```
string error = ErrorGetResProp.GetValue(args.Exception) as string;
List<XmlSchemaException> e = null;
if (!exps.TryGetValue(error, out e))
  exps[error] = e = new List<XmlSchemaException>();

e.Add(args.Exception);
```

After this you have a dictionary `exps` which contains all different error types in `Keys` (didn't quickly find documentation about possible values, but it could be quite easily manually gathered). The values in the dictionary would provide the errors, so you can easily `Count()` them, or display the `Message`, and also `LineNumber`s etc.

There is also another non-public property, `Args`, which would tell the element names and other information, so you can also get that if needed. If you want to group by "element X missing", the information is there.

Also you can naturally group by just the message, but it might not provide enough grouping.

Of course this won't help if memory runs out while validating, but at least it would provide a better way of handling the types of errors.

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I asked about. Thanks a lot!